# Reassociation of DNA

Tags: dna, homework

What is the order in which this DNA samples would would reassociate ?

e.coli DNA

plasmid DNA

viral DNA

satellite DNA

DNA-RNA hybrid

This is a homework question and I have not been given any information about the condition in which they are reassociated.

Comment: RNA-DNA hybrids have a higher thermodynamic stability compared to DNA-DNA hybrids (`deltaG(hybridization)`) is low. However that doesn't really mean they will form faster. Just that the equilibrium is towards association.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rate is determined by the size and complexity of the sequence. Short, non-repetitive sequences should re-associate (at a given r.t.p.) faster than longer, repetitive DNA.

I'm guessing that that is what this question is getting at.